# Window location not working and not redirecting page

Tags: javascript, redirect

My script is this:

```js
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('איזור מוגן! אנא הכנס ססמא',' ');
while (testV < 3) {
if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {
window.open('https://www.lior.vip/live2');
break;
}
testV+=1;
var pass1 =
prompt('ססמא שגויה! אנא נסה שוב');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
window.open('https://www.lior.vip/live2');
}
</SCRIPT>
```

When the correct password entered, it should redirect the user to a new page but the problem is that the new page opens in a new tab.
I want the page to appear at the same window.. (like we can do with "_self" in "a href" tags.

I tried to change the "window.open" with "window.location="
but nothing happens.

How can I approach the task?

Answer (score -1):

Try using instead of window.open use **window.location = "";**

Comment: OP said: `I tried to change the "window.open" with "window.location=" but nothing happens`